# Ошибка "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer cannot be cast to..."

Tags: java, opengl

Пытаюсь запустить программу в Eclipse выдает ошибку. Помогите разобраться.

Ошибка:

> `Exception in thread "Timer-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer cannot be cast to com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo`

Программа написана на OpenGL + Java.

Comment: У Вас в программе ошибка. Проявляется во время исполнения.

Comment: Ну а код то где? Мы же не телепаты чтобы понять откуда идет ошибка

Comment: Это пример из уроков по OpenGL (конкретно 11)
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/flag-effect-waving-texture-nehe-tutorial-jogl-port.html
Там же есть ссылка на дистрибутив всех уроков/примеров
Я Просто скопировал  все в Eclipse и при попытке запустить любой пример выдает эту ошибку

Comment: @serhio28, Вы полагаете здесь много желающих исследовать какие-то курсы ?

Comment: стек ошибки я написал,ничего исследовать не нужно. Меня интересует причина ошибки . код правильный , по крайней мере  Eclipse ошибок не указывает .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина ошибки - **cannot be cast to** :

```
java.nio.DirectByteBuffer cannot be cast to com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo
```

Comment: По русски означает что тип java.nio.DirectByteBuffer не может быть приведен к типу com.sun.opengl.impl.windows.JAWT_Win32DrawingSurfaceInfo